# mbed: HardFault Error when accessing SD-Card after building up network connection

Tags: http, sd-card, mbed, nucleo

I want to combine a HTTP-Client and a SD-Card-Reader. My goal is to download a file from a server and save that file on the SD-Card. Unfortunately Im stuck on the way, because of an Hard Fault 0x80FF013D.

I haven broken down the code and recognized in summary:

- network communication (GET-command) works fine solo
- SD-Card access (read and write) works fine solo
- SD-Card access works fine before building up the network connection
- Hard Fault occures, when I access the SD-Card after building up the network connection

Core-Infos:

- OS: MBED OS5
- IDE: MBED CLI v1.8.2
- MC: NUCLEO-F746ZG
- SD-Card Reader: CATALEX MicroSD Card Adapter with Transcend 2GB microSD (FAT formatted)

Libraries:

- mbed-os
  https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/#e1bea44212b8275f7d8ce7253e758c2e25c57482
- sd-driver https://github.com/ARMmbed/sd-driver/#a8c85d30af86a7431d85dee02d133d60dd386406

### Serial Output with HardFault:

> [NWKH] Connecting to network...
>   [NWKH] Connected to the network
>   [NWKH] IP address: 192.168.188.29
>   Test SD-Card
>
> ++ MbedOS Fault Handler ++
>
> FaultType: HardFault
>
> Context:
>   R0   : 20000400
>   R1   : BFF39B82
>   R2   : 08025B6A
>   R3   : 00000003
>   R4   : 00000000
>   R5   : 2000FA34
>   R6   : 84551677
>   R7   : 7FFFFC00
>   R8   : 00000003
>   R9   : 08025B6A
>   R10  : 2000FA34
>   R11  : 00000000
>   R12  : 08013E6D
>   SP   : 2000F9F8
>   LR   : 0801A8E7
>   PC   : A0000000
>   xPSR : 210B0000
>   PSP  : 2000F990
>   MSP  : 2004FFC0
>   CPUID: 410FC271
>   HFSR : 40000000
>   MMFSR: 00000001
>   BFSR : 00000000
>   UFSR : 00000000
>   DFSR : 0000000B
>   AFSR : 00000000
>   Mode : Thread
>   Priv : Privileged
>   Stack: PSP
>
> -- MbedOS Fault Handler --
>
> ++ MbedOS Error Info ++
>   Error Status: 0x80FF013D Code: 317 Module: 255
>   Error Message: Fault exception
>   Location: 0x8012A7B
>   Error Value: 0xA0000000
>   Current Thread: Id: 0x2000DA34 Entry: 0x8012BEB StackSize: 0x2000 StackMem: 0x2000DA78 SP: 0x2004FF58
>   For more info, visit: https://armmbed.github.io/mbedos-error/?error=0x80FF013D
>   -- MbedOS Error Info --

I have started with the http-example from mbed https://os.mbed.com/teams/sandbox/code/http-example/file/2efadc4d8784/source/main-http-socket-reuse.cpp/shortlog/

and added some stuff from the sd card file system example
https://os.mbed.com/cookbook/SD-Card-File-System

### main-http.cpp

```
#include "select-demo.h"

#if DEMO == DEMO_HTTP

#include "mbed.h"
#include "http_request.h"
#include "network-helper.h"
#include "mbed_mem_trace.h"
#include "SDBlockDevice.h"
#include "FATFileSystem.h"
#include "DebouncedIn.h"

#define SD_MOUNT_PATH           "sd"
#define FULL_UPDATE_FILE_PATH   "/" SD_MOUNT_PATH "/" MBED_CONF_APP_UPDATE_FILE

SDBlockDevice sd(MBED_CONF_APP_SD_CARD_MOSI, MBED_CONF_APP_SD_CARD_MISO,
                 MBED_CONF_APP_SD_CARD_SCK, MBED_CONF_APP_SD_CARD_CS);
FATFileSystem fs(SD_MOUNT_PATH);

NetworkInterface* network;
DebouncedIn btn(USER_BUTTON);

FILE* file;

int main() 
{
/*------Init SD-Card-----------*/
    int r;
    //Init
    if ((r = sd.init()) != 0) {
        printf("Could not initialize SD driver (%d)\n", r);
        return 1;
    }

    //Mount
    if ((r = fs.mount(&sd)) != 0) {
        printf("Could not mount filesystem, is the SD card formatted as FAT? (%d)\n", r);
        return 1;
    }

 /*------Init Network-----------*/  
    network = connect_to_default_network_interface();
    if (!network) 
    {
        printf("Cannot connect to the network, see serial output\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Write
    printf("Test SD-Card\n");
    char testbuffer2[] = { 'a' , 'b' , 'c' };
    file = fopen("/sd/test.bin", "wb");
    fwrite("abc",1,3,file);
    //fwrite(testbuffer2,1,sizeof(testbuffer2),file);
    fclose(file);

//Hauptschleife 
    while(1)
    {
        //Buttondruck
        if (btn.rising())
        {
            printf("Update wird gesucht, bitte warten\n");
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

### mbed_app.json

```
{
    "config": {
        "main-stack-size": {
            "value": 8192
        },

        "update_file": {
            "help": "Path to the application update binary on the SD card",
            "value": "\"update.bin\""
        },

        "sd_card_mosi": {
            "help": "MCU pin connected to the SD card's SPI MOSI pin",
            "value": "D11"
        },
        "sd_card_miso": {
            "help": "MCU pin connected to the SD card's SPI MISO pin",
            "value": "D12"
        },
        "sd_card_sck": {
            "help": "MCU pin connected to the SD card's SPI SCK pin",
            "value": "D13"
        },
        "sd_card_cs": {
            "help": "MCU pin connected to the SD card's SPI CS pin",
            "value": "D10"
        }
    },
    "macros": [
        "MBEDTLS_MPI_MAX_SIZE=1024",
        "MBEDTLS_MPI_WINDOW_SIZE=1",
        "MBEDTLS_USER_CONFIG_FILE=\"mbedtls_entropy_config.h\"",
        "MBEDTLS_TEST_NULL_ENTROPY",
        "MBEDTLS_NO_DEFAULT_ENTROPY_SOURCES",
        "MBED_HEAP_STATS_ENABLED=1"
    ],
    "target_overrides": {
        "*": {
            "platform.stdio-baud-rate": 115200,
            "platform.stdio-convert-newlines": true,
            "mbed-mesh-api.6lowpan-nd-channel-page": 0,
            "mbed-mesh-api.6lowpan-nd-channel": 12,
            "mbed-trace.enable": 1,
            "platform.error-hist-enabled": 1,
            "mbed-http.http-buffer-size": 2048,
            "nsapi.default-wifi-security": "WPA_WPA2",
            "nsapi.default-wifi-ssid": "\"SSID\"",
            "nsapi.default-wifi-password": "\"Password\""
        }
    }
}
```

I have already read the Tutorial for "Analyzing Mbed OS crash dump" -> https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.8/tutorials/analyzing-mbed-os-crash-dump.html,
 but I have still no idea what I can do, to find the reason for the Hard Fault.

- Error Status: "0x80FF013D" means "Hard Fault exception"
- HFSR: 40000000 means "Forced Hard Fault"
- MMFSR: 00000001 means "The processor attempted an instruction fetch from a location that does not permit execution."
- UFSR: 00000000 means "everything is good"
- BFSR: 00000000 means "everything is good"

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This board has conflict pin D11. It used by ethernet and both your SPI. You need to use another SPI pins or follow [guide](https://os.mbed.com/teams/ST/wiki/Nucleo-144pins-ethernet-spi-conflict) from mbed site to fix board:

> If you use **both SPI and Ethernet** You have to patch the NUCLEO board on the back side:
>
> 1. remove SB121 and close SB122 solder bridges. This will
>    connect PB_5 to D11 instead of PA_7.
> 2. Overwrite the d11_configuration by using the mbed_app.json file and use PB_5 (instead of PA_7 default value).